# Which caulk to use on brick facade around electrical outlet

Tags: caulking, sealant

I'm looking to replace the cover of this electrical outlet on the front brick facade of my house. The previous cover was not caulked or anything and was completely open to the elements (you can kind of see the gap between the mortar and the cover in the picture below)

Since it's the front of the house, I'd like for it to look decent and since it's a porous surface I'm concerned that if I mess it up I won't be able to fix it.

Would appreciate any tips, including what type of caulk to get.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Silicon for outdoor/exterior uses.

Comment: Are you under the misaprehension that brick is waterproof,  or do you have some other reason to want to caulk here?

Comment: Those covers are intended to be used with sealed exterior boxes, and come with a gasket to seal them to the box. They are not intended, and not approved, for using on top of random exterior house surfaces. Putting caulk around the cover will probably not have any useful purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Clear silicone is an option.  It will last a long time.  It's going to be visible but as long as you don't get it all over the place it will look good.

Keep in mind the existing cover type is not approved anymore.  You'll need to upgrade to an in-use box, which is a larger part that covers the end of the cords too.  By the time you've done the work to disassmble the old cover, you may as well take out the receptacle too, and upgrade it to a WR type.  This is something you will prefer to figure out before caulking a new cover.

[image: In use box with clear silicone caulk.]

Here is an extra-duty in-use box that I sealed with clear silicone.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. The pictured cover that I'm holding in my hand by Leviton is considered an "in-use" box, wouldn't that work? I was planning to use that and also replace the receptacle with a weather resistant one. There's already a GFCI receptacle on the same circuit.

Comment: @Bynming I can't determine that from the photo.  It looks very shallow.  NEC 406.9(B)(1) requires a product rated "extra-duty" which is usually a few inches deep or more.

Comment: @Bynming Example photo added.

Comment: If you're gonna caulk around it, leave the bottom open just in case.

Comment: Maybe the photo is misleading, but the one I'm looking to install is pretty thick. It's a Leviton 5981-UCL and spec says it's 3.08 inches thick. Thanks for the picture,clear silicone looks like it'll be the ticket. Cheers.

Comment: @Bynming Yes that's a good part.  Gotta disagree with Huesmann: Caulk all the way around to keep spiders out.

Comment: Alright! Thanks Robert, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Get a water-resistant rated box and replace whole box. This ensures safety, as long as the box is oriented correctly.
You can install the box using mortar, or caulk it with outdoor rated silicone.
It is also a good idea to check that the outlet is protected with GFCI breaker.

Answer (score -1):

The outlet cover should seal to the electrical box and that itself should be waterproof, so there's no need for additional waterproofing.

Bricks aren't waterproof anyway.

They make a tinted sandy caulk that should match the mortar and bricks fairly well, use that if you need to fill the cracks for some other reason.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It has a foam backing that would probably seal just fine against a flat surface but not against bricks. I don't want to make it fully waterproof, I just want to prevent rain and snow melt to easily get into the box.